# Laravel 5 ignore Authentication specific route

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, token

I am new in laravel 5. I have a dashboard page and a login page. whenever I go to `localhost:8080/dashboard` it always redirect me to `localhost:8080/auth/login`.

I wanted to show my dashboard `localhost:8080/dashboard` to be viewed without logging in first. Here is my code in `VerifyCsfrToken`

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */


    protected $except_urls = [
        'dashboard/dashboard',
    ];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $regex = '#' . implode('|', $this->except_urls) . '#';

        if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request) || preg_match($regex, $request->path()))
        {
            return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
        }

        throw new TokenMismatchException;

        return parent::handle($request, $next);
    }

}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'ReservationController@index');

 Route::controllers([
'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
 ]);
```

controller :

```
use App\reservations;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Request;

class ReservationController extends Controller {

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Welcome Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller renders the "marketing page" for the application and
| is configured to only allow guests. Like most of the other sample
| controllers, you are free to modify or remove it as you desire.
|
*/

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application welcome screen to the user.
 *
 * @return Response
 */

public function schedule()
{
    $schedules = schedules::all();


    return view('calendar.schedule',compact('schedules'));
}
public function index()
{
return view('dashboard.dashboard');
}
public function create()
{

    return view('reserve.reserve');
}
public function update()
{
    return view('calendar.update');
}
public function login()
{
    return view('login');
}

public function store(Requests\CreateReservationRequest $request)
{

    $input = Request::all();
    $reservation = new reservations(['user_id'       => '13100024',
                                    'status_id'     => '1',
                                    'room_id'       => $input['room'],
                                    'purpose'       => $input['purpose'],
                                    'start_time'    => $input['date']."        ".$input['hour1'].":".$input['minute1'].":00",
                                    'end_time'      => $input['date']." ".$input['hour2'].":".$input['minute2'].":00",
                                    'add_date'      => Carbon::now()
                                    ]);
    $reservation->save();

    return "success";
   // return redirect('schedule');

   }
```

Comment: Could you show use some more code? maybe your routes or your controller as I don't think the issue is int the csrf class.

Comment: this is my routes.php

Comment: @Szenis i already edited my question

Comment: Do you not have a constructor for your controller? Laravel shouldn't redirect you unless you're using the `auth` middleware somewhere.

Comment: Add the full `ReservationController` Code. You have an auth filter/middleware lurking somewhere in there.

Comment: @Styphon i have a __construct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what causes the issue:

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

It restricts access to the page to logged in users. Just remove it from your controller and users will be able to access the page whether they're logged in or not.

Comment: hi yeah. but i wanted it to be restricted only for a specific page.

Comment: for example i want to view a page first before going to log in page sir

Comment: @kevin_marcus, follow the instructions above. Then in your `index()` function in the `ReservationController`, check if the user is logged in, using `auth::check()`. If they are, display your user view page, else present your guest view page. Read more about authentication here: http://laravelbook.com/laravel-user-authentication/

Comment: @kevin_marcus using a different controller for the page you do want restricted is the best way to do this.

Comment: @Mysteryos that site is for Laravel 4.

Comment: @Styphon dude. thanks a lot! it helped me. i just created a separate controller. thanks man

Answer (score -1):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['Whatever You want to Bypass']]);
}
```

Comment: Please don't give an answer as code only, without a description